# Do I always need a discrete graphics card together with a Ryzen 2600?

Tags: graphics-card, amd-ryzen, discrete-graphics

I know that the Ryzen 2600 is not an "APU", so for gaming use, I would need to get a separate, discrete, graphics card. However, I see that some AM4 boards claim to have an "Onboard APU" (e.g. [this one](https://www.tms.co.il/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=17861)) - so maybe for basic 2D desktop work, I don't the discreet card after all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do, the reason it says onboard APU is because before GPU on CPU you had onboard graphics where they had their own GPU chips on the Motherboard. it's saying it has onboard display output for an APU. so if you don't install an APU chip these outputs won't have a GPU to power them and as such won't work.

**Updates moving forward of 2023**
As of Ryzen 5000 this is starting to change your getting CPUs with integrated graphics on them no longer called APU's much like the intel counter part.

Comment: That's too bad, but thank you.